# Are these called String Formatters?

Tags: string, syntax, formatting

What are these "character sequences that represent an operation" called?

```
print("The value of x is $%a", x)
```

> The value of x is 4

There's also a different one that represents an exception for any word in String.Find.

```
string str1 = "I like bacon.";
string str2 = "I love bacon.";
Debug.WriteLine(String.Find(str1, "I #$ Bacon")); >> True
Debug.WriteLine(String.Find(str2, "I #$ Bacon")); >> True
```

Literally for years I've wondered what they were called, as I there were many instances they could've come in handy; had I remembered them.

Comment: _Formatting placeholders_ seems to be a more appropriate term.

Comment: In C++ you should be using the [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) instead of a C style `printf`.

Comment: I would expect the documentation for `String` (whatever that is) to establish some terminology for its metacharacters. (Did you misspell C# when you tagged this?)

Comment: `String.Find` and `True` are not standard C++. If you're using some C++ variant you should indicate what that is; similarly, if that comes from some library, you should indicate what that is.

Comment: @Ron: No you shouldn't.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley All the C++ heavyweights I talked to say you should. Care to expand on that?

Comment: It wasn't C++. That's supposed to be aside the point, because the topic is what those characters are called. But if it means so much, anyway, here:
Debug.WriteLine(String.Find(str2, "I #$ Bacon"))
>> Still True

Comment: @Ron: You should use whatever you are more comfortable with. But, in my opinion, storing information about how to handle formatting in the stream object itself is a ridiculous idea. Many people, myself included, also find that printf style format string, where all the text is in one place, much more legible than the iostream style, where you've got some text, then it's interrupted by `<< some_variable <<`, followed by a little more text, then another interruption, etc...

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C and C++ they are referred to as ["format specifiers"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), "*placeholders*" or "*formatting placeholders*". Your code however doesn't appear to be standard C nor C++.